# Can't open a certain website – which proxy for Firefox should I use?

Tags: firefox, proxy

I can't open pages like `microsoft.com`.

I think my internet provider is filtering these pages. What can you recommend for me as proxy for Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean [lists of proxys you can use](http://www.google.de/search?q=proxy+list)? A proxy doesn't care what browser you use so you don't need to search for "mozilla proxies".

Unless you pay for your proxy account, it is very likely that using the proxies you find out in the wild is not exactly legal and slow.

As Molly said, you really might want to have a look at Tor.

Answer (score 3):

Try the **[Tor Browser Bundle for Windows](http://www.torproject.org/download.html.en)** (Contains Tor, Vidalia, Torbutton, Polipo, and Firefox)

Comment: But I want something like proxy proxy I mean server!

Comment: @oneat - umm, Tor will be routing your traffic through web proxies ... free and without configuration, just press the Tor button :)

Answer (score 3):

It could be that you have a spyware/virus infection. These often block updates to Microsoft.com, to stop you downloading updates.

Comment: Yes, It's I terminated one svchost process and everything works :D.
But or it's infected orginal svchost or smart virus.

Comment: The virus writers are pretty smart...

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you have a virus. Your ISP would never block microsoft.com. Having a proxy is not your problem. Remove the virus or do a clean install of Windows or try a different browser.